# How do I use VisualStudio git extensions to access remote repository using password access?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, git-extensions

I have a remote git server that does not support registering a public key for authentication purposes and instead requires a password. When pushing to this server via the command line, I can enter a password and it works OK.

When I try to push to the same remote repository using Visual Studio with git extensions, the push just locks up as it is being asked for the password, but doesn't seem to be able to handle that. I can't figure out where in the git extensions configuration I specify the password.

Am I missing the obvious?? If so, how do I configure the password? Or is it a case that git extensions only works with private/public key authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's a missing feature. Git extensions only support private/public key authentication. You'll have to use the command line for https and password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your password and username, you may be able to use the username:password url format to access the repo over https thusly:

```
https://username:password@domain.tld/repo-path
```

For example, if I access a github repo using that format with a password that works for that format (i.e. doesn't have ":" or "@" in it; there are probably other characters that would break it but those ones clearly will) I get read-write access to the repo over http(s).

Of course this is completely insecure, but in a pinch it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately as it's horribly insecure! :) this didn't work for me.